# Definition for swift annotated apis

Tags: swift

I was reading this link https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/swift/conceptual/buildingcocoaapps/WorkingWithCocoaDataTypes.html and in the section regarding Memory Managed Objects, they talk about annotated APIs. However, I can't find a definition for annotated APIs. Anyone know what that means?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Essentially, Apple is having to go through all their APIs and annotate each function with information about the allocation of memory for parameters and return values. Once that's done, annotated functions can be used from within Swift more easily, since the compiler knows what it has to do to safely bridge types back and forth from Swift code to annotated C code.

Here's an example of similar annotated and unannotated functions. First, the C versions:

```
// Creates an immutable copy of a string.
CFStringRef CFStringCreateCopy ( CFAllocatorRef alloc, CFStringRef theString );

// Encodes an OSType into a string suitable for use as a tag argument.
CFStringRef UTCreateStringForOSType ( OSType inOSType );
```

Both of these functions return a `CFStringRef` - a reference to a `CFString`. A C `CFString` can be bridged to a Swift `CFString` instance, but this is only safe if the method has been annotated. Here are the Swift versions:

```
// annotated: returns a memory-managed Swift `CFString`
func CFStringCreateCopy(alloc: CFAllocator!, theString: CFString!) -> CFString!

// unannotated: returns an *unmanaged* `CFString`
func UTCreateStringForOSType(inOSType: OSType) -> Unmanaged<CFString>!
```

If you're calling the second one, you'll need to call `.takeRetainedValue()` or `.takeUnretainedValue()` on the result to get a memory-managed `CFString` instance - to know which one, you'll have to read the documentation or know the conventions to understand whether the result you get back is retained or unretained. With annotated functions, Apple has already done this work for you.

There are a couple threads in the forums on the subject, since Apple is also indicating whether or not return values should be optional with its annotations, but they're keeping things pretty close at this point.